# Spring Batch and Executors Framework

Tags: spring-batch, threadpoolexecutor, executor, scheduledexecutorservice, executors

Are these 2 Frameworks used for same purpose. If not why and how these are used in real time applications ? Are there any tutorials to learn these.

Comment: These are really apples and oranges.  What problem are you looking to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring batch is meant for batch processing of files by executing them in a series of jobs .Batch processing could be reading from CSV or XML or any flat file and write it to DB .Spring Batch provides many made Classes to read/write CSV, XML and database.
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-batch-tutorial/

Java Executor service on the other hand is all about spawning multiple threads in a thread pool and executing them for any purpose be it  batch or anything else,but here you have better control because of transaction management.Also , its a feature introduced from Java 5 onwards.Also there are many methods depends on you want to compute on a response or you don't want a response from future object .
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html